# Google Access token server side validation for android app

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm developing android application, that is based on communication with server, and I want to use Google(g+) authentication mechanisms.

Basically, I think it should work like this:

1. In my android app, user logs in to Google, using his email and password.
2. User allows access to his data for related Google application.
3. My android app receives access token, after successful log in.
4. In further communication with my server, my android application should using received Google access token (for example: in queries).
5. When my server receives some query from android app, with access token, it should ask    Google that this token is valid (and for who), and if yes, server should assume that user is authenticated with Google.

My question is: how the server should ask Google if given access token is valid? I think I should somehow check if the token is valid for my android app.

I've tried many Google queries to Google API, that I've found, but nothing worked as I expected. Can you provide me some example?

Comment: I am not sure about the question. Since your app is directly communicating with the google servers, where does your personal server comes into picture? You can check token validity in your android app itself. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i'm already getting access token from g+ in client app(android), i am send that access token to my server , in that server i want to re validate that access token that was fired from Google or not and i need to get user info...using that access token....thank for response

Comment: Try any operation. Like search or upload or anything if token is valid you will get the response or else you will receive an "unauthorized" response. Typically the token expires every one hour or when user explicitly changes google password. If you have done the authentication properly you must have received refresh token with access token. Use this refresh token to get new access token.

Comment: @BhargavMethuku  Can you provide me you code where u r obtaining the access token and sending to server. Moreover i guess you must have validated it too. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can validate if the `access_token` is valid or not.

You need to send `GET` request to the api end point : `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo` with your access_token in request.

You can try it like this:

```
 String connection = new ConnectionService().connectionGoogle("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo", "access_token=" + "YOUR_EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN");
        System.out.println(connection);
```

**The methods used in above code are:**

```
public static String connectionGoogle(String url, String parameter) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {

        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        request1.setRequestMethod("GET");
        request1.setDoOutput(true);
        request1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(request1.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(parameter);
        wr.flush();
        request1.connect();
        String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
        wr.close();
        return responseBody;
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanku for Your response!! but we are expecting UserInfo ...
but now i'm validating with using Googlecredential Class...

Comment: @BhargavMethuku so you are able to get the userinfo now.right??

Comment: My server is written in node. I want to send access token to my server and then validate it there.! how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tokeninfo endpoint to check a token (access or ID token). If you just want to play with the API, you can use the [TokenInfo API from the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo).

You can use the Google-provided library for OAuth v2 to perform the API calls.

You can also form the URL and perform a GET query as described in the [OAuth v2 Playground documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken).